# How to show address below the google maps while moving the maps in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am using google maps in project.. and i am getting current location only.. but i need to show the current location in label and if i move maps then label address also need to change, how to do that

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import GooglePlaces

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 
@IBOutlet weak var belowaddressLabel: UILabel!

 @IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!
 
 private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     
     locationManager.delegate = self
     locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 }

}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
// 2
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
// 3
guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
    return
}
 
// 4
 locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

//5
googleMapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
 googleMapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
 }

 // 6
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
guard let location = locations.first else {
    return
 }

// 7
 googleMapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

// 8
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
}
```

here i need to show current location address in `belowaddressLabel` how?, please help me with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation) to get the address based on the coordinates passed in `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`.

```swift
// 7
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
    guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
    self.belowaddressLabel.text = placemark.name
})
```

Note that you can get the street, city, etc from placemark. See [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark) docs.

Comment: i didn't get you, may i know where excatly i should write `self.belowaddressLabel.text = placemark.name`

Comment: Place that code snippet after `// 7` in your code.